# IIS default datetime format

Tags: wcf, datetime, iis, locale

We have a WCF web service returns back some xml containing a datetime value as a string.  The value is first read out from a database and then appended to an xml string using .ToString().

We have a number of web servers running but this particular one is converting the datetime value to a 24 hour value, we need it has a 12 hour value but I can't figure out how to change IIS default date format.  I have tried changing the regional settings and have look at the culture and ui culture values of the web service which are both set to "Invariant Language (Invariant Country)".

I think it might require a registry change.  Does anyone know how to change the datetime format of a web service?

We cannot change the code at this stage so my only choice is to update the server itself.

Its running on windows server 2008.

thank you

Comment: Did you check the regional settings for the user running your webservice?

Comment: Do you mean the IIS user or the user account that was used to start the web service?

Comment: I mean the account that actually runs the WCF service (see user column in the task manager). Or does it run inside a IIS app pool? Then it would be this user...

Comment: It runs inside an app pool.  In this case how would I check the app pool user's datetime format settings? or that of the app pool itself? I understand I can change the culture under .net globalization, I have tried this but it didn't help

Comment: Why can't you change the code?  That would be the correct way.

Comment: Yeah that would be the correct way but unfortunately its simply not possible at the moment and we this to work urgently.  I think there must be some way to change it on the server but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind people I've figured it out.  To change the datetime regional settings of an IIS website/webs ervice here is what you do:

First go into IIS and click on the website/web service you want to configure.  On the right hand side open up .Net Globalization and change the culture and ui culture to anything other than the one you want.

Now in the control panel go into the region and language screen and change the datetime format to what you want it to be.  Then on the administration tab of the region and language screen click the "Copy settings" button and tick the box "Welcome screen and system accounts".  Click ok on both screens to exit region and language.

Now go back to IIS and change the culture and ui culture back to what it was before you change it.  Your website/webservice should now be serving up the correct datetime format.

I think the key point here is copying the region and language settings to all system users.  then changing the IIS culture settings makes IIS pickup the new settings.  You might get away with not changing the culture and simply restarting the webserver or the machine after making the changes in the region and language screen but i haven't tried this.