# How to read the Control Panel settings through IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an application in which I have to show the currency input fields by picking up the settings from (**in Windows: Control Panel > Region and Language > Additional Settings > Digit grouping symbol**). For e.g.**1,234,567.89**. If I change my Digit grouping symbol to apostrophe(') then the result would be **1'234'567.89**. For this I am using the following code:

```
    int value = 123456789;
    string output = (value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    Response.Write(output);
```

The above code gives me the output like **123"456"789.00 €**. Because my Digit grouping symbol is(**"**).

When I host this page on IIS, it default shows **$123,456,789.00** but my current culture is French and my Digit grouping symbol is(**"**), the output should come **123"456"789.00 €** . Why IIS not picking up my Control Panel settings.

Comment: I need some quick answers please.

Comment: This looks like the same question as [IIS default datetime format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556563/iis-default-datetime-format)